# Octave memory allocation error after changing graphicsmagicks to quantum depth 16

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, ubuntu-14.04, octave, graphicsmagick

I tried to increase the quantum depth of the GraphicsMagick to 16bits. I downloaded the GraphicsMagick package from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/graphicsmagick/). Here is the result for the version details and quantum depth result for `gm version`.

```
karthikeyan@karthikeyan:~$ gm version

GraphicsMagick 1.3.25 2016-09-05 Q16 http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/
Copyright (C) 2002-2016 GraphicsMagick Group.
Additional copyrights and licenses apply to this software.
See http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/www/Copyright.html for details.
..
...
....
Configured using the command:
  ./configure  '--with-quantum-depth=16' '--enable-shared' '--disable-static' '--with-magick-plus-plus=yes'
```

So I went ahead to process images,assuming my graphicsmagick can handle 16 bits, but I am getting this error. Please help to resolve this:

```
karthikeyan@karthikeyan:~$ octave

octave:1> i = imread("/home/karthikeyan/Pictures/Wallpapers/f1376677896.jpg");
warning: your version of GraphicsMagick limits images to 8 bits per pixel
*** Error in `/usr/bin/octave-cli': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000002300dd0 ***
panic: Aborted -- stopping myself...
^C^CPress Control-C again to abort.
^Cpanic: attempted clean up apparently failed -- aborting...
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Have you compiled Octave afterwards?

Comment: You need to rebuild Octave from source if you build GraphicsMagick with different quantum depth. See notes on the [Octave wiki](http://wiki.octave.org/GraphicsMagick)

Comment: @carandraug - The wiki link talks about rebuilding GraphicsMagick, but not Octave. I am confused in what order to do, and if I used `apt-get` for Octave, then how to rebuild Octave. Any links, please?

Comment: @Andy - I use `apt-get` to install Octave; not complied through downloaded packages. Will this be the right way to rebuild - http://askubuntu.com/questions/652004/ddg#670818 ?

Comment: @karthikeyan: If you want to compile Octzave from source then first compile graphicsmagick like pointed out by carandraug and afterwars octave. Please read http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Debian_systems

Comment: @Andy-Thanks a lot. I removed all; and then reinstalled in the order as you said. Its working; Thanks a lot.